Is massage therapy a qualified medical expense without a LMN?
FSAfeds.gov (an official government website) states that massage therapy is a qualified medical expense, therefore reimbursable from an FSA/HSA.

However, numerous other websites would state that it is only qualified with a Letter of Medical Necessity (LMN) from a doctor.
The IRS Pub 502 does not mention massages as all. How do I know whether or not it is qualified?

I'll note that if your motivation for asking this question is that you wish to burn out your FSA, I'd suggest looking at the IRS's list of expenses to consider.  Quoting the IRS, there are "Many over-the-counter items that are FSA eligible." A popular choice would be to just buy a year supply of sunscreen.

Over the counter services require a letter of medical necessity to be a qualified medical expense. If a doctor says you need a massage then it is a qualified expense, if you just went to a spa on vacation then it is not.

I know what OTC drugs are, but services? Can you clarify?

What's not clear? Things you don't need prescription for. Like massages

Determinations of eligibility are not made by FSAFeds.
FSAFeds should not be treated as official guidance.  Quoting FSAFeds.gov: "Even though an item may be found in a list, it does not guarantee reimbursement. Any expenses that are listed as potentially eligible may require additional documentation such as a Letter of Medical Necessity."
FSA benefits are managed by your employer (typically by hiring a third-party company).
I would expect such plans to mostly match any official guidance issued by the IRS.   The many websites saying that massage requires a letter of medical necessity suggests that FSA plans have mostly converged on that behavior, but it's possible that not all require it.  It's also possible some plans do not cover massage even with a letter of medical necessity.
If you wish to verify FSA eligbility, I recommend consulting your FSA plan document (under ERISA, such a document must exist).
